# Where to put your Google Analytics code

Tags: google-analytics, seo, analytics

I know this question is asked before but because Google is conflicting itself in their support I was confused.

When generating a Google analytics code, Google Analytics tells me to put my tracking code immediately after the opening body tag:
[image: print screen google analytics]

However, I read on the Google support forum that it should be inside my `<head>` tag.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en-GB

> Paste your snippet (unaltered, in it’s entirety) into every web page that you want to track. Paste it immediately before the closing `</head>` tag.

Anyone knows which one is best?

Comment: On https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingOverview?hl=nl it states: 'This tracking code snippet should be included in your site's pages so that it appears at the bottom of the page's HTML (or generated-HTML) structure, before the closing <body> tag.' - Rather conflicting..

Comment: @GeertJaminon, that's not really conflicting - the "traditional" syntax mentioned in the linked article is deprecated (back in those  days the code was synchronously loaded and put in the footer as to avoid blocking).

Comment: @EikePierstorff It does state: 'Last updated juli 15, 2014.'

Comment: It also says "As part of the Universal Analytics Upgrade, we recommend you use a newer version of this library. Learn how to upgrade to Universal Analytics."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as it's enclosed properly between `<script>` tags, it should work anyway. The only tradeoff being that:

- including it in the `<head>` section would result in a slower page rendering (because it would execute the js before parsing the rest of the page)
- including it in the bottom of the page might not count people that land in your page, stay for 3 seconds and leave.

The latter  won't happen in small pages, but I've seen it happen in forums and blogs where there is a lot of html rendering, a couple of feet of scrolling below the fold and the page completion takes several seconds. In those cases it is possible for people to leave before GA snippet is executed.

Current analytics code is asynchronous so even if you put it in the head it shouldn't affect the rendering time but in a few miliseconds.

TL/DR it's about the same when it comes to normal pages

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, I get that it works always, that's what I discovered too. However my Google tag assistant gives me a warning when it is outside my <head> tag. So I'm asking myself  if they can measure better one way or the other.

Comment: Being in the head gives them the fastest response time, so that's why they want to be in there.

Comment: Also you cannot use it to verify Google Webmaster Tools accounts if it's in the wrong place. Given that you gain absolutely nothing by placing it in the footer you should go with the Google documentation.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Which one of them? ;-)

Comment: @GeertJaminon you got me there :-) Let's agree on "put it somewhere on the top of the page", okay :-)

Comment: @EikePierstorff well, there are other ways to get Google Webmaster Tools verification. I use CNAME and html file mostly. But yes, that's a point in favor of HEAD

Answer (score 2):

As long as you place the code as it appears from Google, the tracking will fire.

The higher on the page you have your code, the better your stats will be.

For example, if you have a user with a slow internet connection (think smart phone with poor signal) and your page takes 3 seconds to load.  If you have your tracking code higher on the page, the code will fire sooner and start tracking the user's time on site, including the bulk of the load time.

Say in the above example, that the GA code is the very last tag on the site, and after 2 seconds the user sees a link they're looking for, and clicks that link before the page has fully loaded.  In this case, the GA code may never fire from the bottom of the page, and you've missed analytics on a hit/visit/visitor that actually went to your site.

Having the GA code in the header or near the top of your code DOES NOT have to slow down the load time.  You can call the GA code **asynchronously** to keep it from slowing down the rest of the load (documented here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, okay so just as arnenadiel says it's best practice to put it just before the `</head>` tag. But why is Google Analytics saying that it should be inserted after the opening `<body>` tag?

Comment: Because there's still a lot of code that can load in the head.  Many sites load massive or multiple CSS and JS files in the head.  Google wants to try to get in front of these.  The other concern is that having a malformed JS that's not closed properly by another developer or plugin, could keep the Google JS from firing at all.  This again could lead to missing out on insights on your visitors/traffic.